# Can you really infuse someone with a coconut?

Tags: realism, who-am-i

In the movie "Who Am I" starring Jackie Chan we see a character giving someone an coconut infusion after they've suffered blood loss.

**Does this really work?**

Comment: Can you? Yes. Should you? Hells no.

Comment: @Richard My original question was Does it help to.. but it got edited.

Comment: Does it help? Put it this way, I'd be happy to try it on **someone else**.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Yes and no.** The way it's depicted in the film, it would have zero effect. You can't simply feed a piece of surgical tubing into someone's vein and rely on capillary action and gravity to infuse their bloodstream with coconut water. Without a tight seal at both ends, the most likely result would be that the person bled out into the coconut or simply bled out where the tube had been inserted

*but wait...*

A [1979 study](http://www.drinkbai.com/blog/coconut-water-pure-can-used-blood-transfusions) did conclude that in a pinch, you could use coconut water as saline replacement fluid without the user suffering *immediate* ill effects but it was stressed that this was an emergency procedure and one that was extremely badly advised when any other form of sterile saline or water was available.